# Get anchor tag value when anchor tag is inside for each loop

Tags: struts2, el, struts-tags

```jsp
<c:forEach items="${customer.iscutomer}">
<div>
<i>${customer.customerNumber}. </i>
    <li>
        <a href="Javascript:void(0)">${customer.customerName}</a>
    </li>
</div>
</c:forEach>
```

i don't know how to get customer name in Struts2 when user selects any          hyerlink(customer name come from customer object).

Comment: Do you have some javascripts that binds to link click?! What happens when user clicks on the link?

Comment: From javascript i am able to get the value of i tag, i just want to find solition with out javascript.

Comment: Yes it seems that you are building the action user in javascript. So you need to get `customerNumber` from there. But if you want to do it without JavaScript you should use `struts tags`, as mentioned by @RomanC, to build the url and add the `customerNumber` to it.

Comment: Yes thats what i want, i am not that much perfect on struts tag, i know javascript and jquery and i find the solution for that as well. It would be good if u provide some code to get those values into struts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this can help you to start:

```
<c:forEach items="${customer.iscutomer}">
<div>
<i>${customer.customerNumber}. </i>
    <li>
        <s:a name="foo" namespace="bar">
              <s:param name="customerName">${customer.customerName}</s:param>
              <s:param name="customerNubmber">${customer.customerNumber}</s:param>
     </s:a>
    </li>
</div>
```

Please consider I find that the `s:a url` does not add parameters to link. Now your generated link will be `/foo/bar/action?customerName=joe&customerNumber=1`

No in your JS you can have:

```
$('a').bind('click',function(){
    var url = ($(this).attr('href'));
    var customerName= getURLParameter(url, 'customerName');
    var customerNumber= getURLParameter(url, 'customerNumber');
    //calling the ajax function
    pop(cat, typ)
});
```

If you want to have ajax calls please have a look at  struts 2 jquery plugin.

Comment: This code doesn't meet solution,what your given solution is already made from my side.I don't want to use JavaScript or jquery, without these i want to achieve solution.Thanks for providing solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Struts anchor tag and add parameter to the URL.

```jsp
<s:a href="url"><s:param name="customerName">${customer.customerName}</s:param>CustomerName</s:a>
```

Note, that you can use EL in the body of the tag.

Comment: When anchor tag execute i have to get the value from <i> tag and place in side bean.

Comment: The `param` tag will parametrize the anchor tag with the value, so you don't have to do it.

Comment: what you r explaning that is correct but i have take customerNumber then only i have to validate from my side

Comment: you can take `customerNumber ` via another `param` tag, you don't need to take it from `<i>` tag.

Comment: Can u provide some code, where i have to keep the parsm tag.

Comment: since i am struggling for last two days hope this time it would be helpfull.

Comment: <s:url action="hello" var="helloLink">
  <s:param name="userName">Bruce Phillips</s:param>
</s:url>
 
<p><a href="${helloLink}">Hello Bruce Phillips</a></p>                                                                                               could you please explain me how its work, thean that would have very helpfull

Comment: i will try in my code, hope it will work and big thanks to you man@roman c